# How to inform Angular directive that the scope values have changed?

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive, isolate-scope

I am trying to create an angular directive that will draw a d3 bar chart. I can't figure out exactly where to add the D3 drawing code so that the chart is redrawn every time the chart values change (the values are tied to an isolate scope). I tried to place this code in the link function, but that renders the chart only once. It is not called every time the scope changes. See code below or a full jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nareshbhatia/jzwzmkxv/).

```
function barchart() {    
    var directive = {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            values: '='
        }
    };
    return directive;

    function link(scope, element) {
        // Draw D3 chart here
        element.html(scope.values);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can $watch for changes:

```
function link(scope, element){
   scope.$watch("values", function(newVal, oldVal){
      // do whatever you need to regenerate the graph
   });
}
```